# Discord.py load_extension Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback"

Tags: discord.py

While running the main.py file i get this error "main.py:15: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
client.load_extension(f"commands.{filename[:-3]}")
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback"

Main.py File

```
import discord
from discord import *
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-", help_command=None,intents=discord.Intents.all())
token = os.getenv("TOKEN")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Rhino Bot is online")
    for filename in os.listdir('./commands'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            client.load_extension(f"commands.{filename[:-3]}")
            print(f"{filename[:-3]} loaded")
        

client.run(token)
```

commands/ban.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands 
import asyncio 
import random



class ban(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1,4,commands.BucketType.user)
    @commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
    async def ban(self, ctx,member : discord.Member,*,reason= "No Reason Provided"):
        guild = ctx.guild
        try:
            embed=discord.Embed(title="Ban ", description=(f"You Have Been Banned From the {guild.name}, Because:"+reason), color=discord.Color.random())
            embed.set_author(name='Rihno Bot',
            icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/935411433380917309/938391346283163678/images.png')
            await member.send(embed=embed)
            await member.ban(reason=reason)
        except:
            embed=discord.Embed(title="Banned ", description=(member.mention + f" has been banned from the server, Because:"+reason), color=discord.Color.random())
            embed.set_author(name='Rihno Bot',
            icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/935411433380917309/938391346283163678/images.png')
            embed=discord.Embed(title='Error', description=("dms are closed so i couldn't dm them ❌"))
            embed.set_author(name='Rihno Bot',
            icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/935411433380917309/938391346283163678/images.png')
        
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await member.ban(reason=reason)
    



def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(ban(client))
```

What should i do? discord.py version using 2.1.0
and platform is replit.................

Answer (score 1):

It's because you added load_extension part without await it so that's why it's causing coroutine error. You can fix this in two ways:

1. Just add this to your place where you added `client.load_extension(f"commands.{filename[:-3]}")`

```
await client.load_extension(f"commands.{filename[:-3]}")
```

2. Can even do something like this, if you don't wanna await:

```
for filename in os.listdir('./commands'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            client.load_extension(f"commands.{filename[:-3]}")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Rhino Bot is online")
```

Comment: same error: 
le_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'commands.ban' raised an error: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression


discord.py latest version